# Can't pull from git if a file is continuously changing

Tags: git

I've added resources/xml to my both the local and remote `.gitignore` files.

```
error: Your local changes to the following files would be overwritten by merge:
resources/xml/analysis.xml
```

My local and remote gitignores both look like:

```
/vendor/
.env
/resources/xml/
```

I can't pull anything, not even stashing `analysis.xml` helps, because 1 sec after stash it has changed again.

**UPDATE**
after removing from cache and deleting the conflicting file from the remote

```
CONFLICT (modify/delete): resources/xml/analysis.xml deleted in 
d58b27586850da80e85119be6005fbe538a5e8ab and modified in HEAD. 
Version HEAD of resources/xml/analysis.xml left in tree.
Automatic merge failed; fix conflicts and then commit the result.
```

after this I needed another `git rm resources/xml/analysis.xml` and I can pull now.
Thanks

Comment: Have you added the file to Git before adding it to `.gitignore`?

Comment: The title should rather read "How to stop process from continously changing my .gitignore?". ;) The problem is, that Git would need to merge the file with the remote changes _after_ getting the remote version (and applying the local version). Do you really need the local changes (made by some process)?

Comment: It's not a line ending issue.

Comment: Could you please add your solution as an answer and check it tomorrow?

Answer (score 3):

It seems the file is being tracked by Git, despite its entry in `.gitignore`.

This happens when you have added the file to Git before, only to `gitignore` afterwards: Git does not remove files from its index when you ignore them but only does not add them to the index.

You need to remove the file from the Git index (but not from your harddrive):

```
git rm --cached resources/xml/analysis.xml
```

or

```
git rm --cached -r resources/xml/
```

when there are additional files you want to remove.

Afterwards, the file will be unknown to Git and will be ignored in the future.

Answer (score 1):

What’s happening here is that Git is protecting you from losing changes in that file.

You may have added the file to your `.gitignore` but that doesn’t tell Git to stop caring about it when it tracks that file. So when you have local changes, and a pull/merge would result in updating the file, Git stops so you don’t lose those local changes.

If you want Git to really forget the file, you will have to remove it from the repository, otherwise Git will not care about what’s in the `.gitignore` about the file. To remove the file from the repository, without deleting the physical file, you can do this:

```
git rm --cached resources/xml/analysis.xml
```

Then you will have to commit that change. Only from then, Git will really ignore the file.

Note that this doesn’t necessarily stop Git from protecting your local file. If you end up merging a commit in which that file still existed and in which it was changed, then Git may end up telling you again, that the file would be touched. So you might want to temporarily rename the file to protect your local changes in those cases.

Note that it’s always a good idea to check the output of `git status` in these situations. It will tell you in your original situation, that the file is still *known* to Git and that it has some uncommitted changes to it.

Comment: :) I'm testing it. Getting some conflicts now